# Similar way of doing "add_interval_job" in c#

Tags: c#, python, quartz.net

We know in Python in the module apscheduler there's this function "add_inverval_job" which allows us to schedule jobs, especially another function with a bunch of arguments. Now I need to implement this in c#. I've gone through Quartz.net. As I understood, the job to be scheduled should be defined in a class inherited from IJob. The problem is the function (job) I want to schedule is composed of provoked functions and parameters from other classes, with lots of arguments. None of the examples I found has a similar case.

I'm wondering if there's a better way in c# which could help me achieve that. Or if somebody could help me that with Quartz.net.

The function I want to add is:

```
private void job_recording(
    string ffmpeg_command, string stream, string cam_ID, int period,
    string vpath, string full_cam_IP, string cam_type, string cam_usr, 
    string cam_pwd)
{
    if (!cam_enabled(cam_ID))
        logger.info ("REC: rec not enabled for %s", cam_ID);
    else
    {
        if (!enable_cam_datetime_setting)
            logger.info('REC: IP camera datetime setting disabled');
        else
        {
            if (cam_type=="axis")
                CSCAMCONFIG.axis_set_datetime(full_cam_IP, cam_usr, cam_pwd);
            else
                logger.info('REC: IP camera datetime not settable');
        }
        string fName=get_fName(cam_ID, period * 60, vpath);
        string command=ffcommand(period, stream, fName);
        //logger
        string rec_process=...;
        set_rec_process(cam_ID, rec_process);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

I think what you need is to use the JobDataMap - essentially is allows you to pass an arbitrary set of parameters into your job handling class

So - you would add the job as follows (code no compilable!) ....

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<RecordingJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1") // name "myJob", group "group1"
    .UsingJobData("ffmpeg_command", "*some command*")
    .UsingJobData("stream", "*some stream*")
      // Add all your other params here ...
    .Build();
```

And you job class would look like this (again not compilable) ...

```
public class RecordingJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
      JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;

      JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

      string ffmpeg_command= dataMap.GetString("ffmpeg_command");
      float stream= dataMap.GetFloat("stream");

      // file out the rest of the parameters

      job_recording(ffmpeg_command, stream ...... );
    }

        // and your job func here 
     private void job_recording(
             string ffmpeg_command, string stream, string cam_ID, int period,
             string vpath, string full_cam_IP, string cam_type, string cam_usr, 
             string cam_pwd)
     {
        if (!cam_enabled(cam_ID))
            logger.info ("REC: rec not enabled for %s", cam_ID);
        else
        {
            if (!enable_cam_datetime_setting)
                logger.info('REC: IP camera datetime setting disabled');
            else
            {
                if (cam_type=="axis")
                    CSCAMCONFIG.axis_set_datetime(full_cam_IP, cam_usr, cam_pwd);
                else
                    logger.info('REC: IP camera datetime not settable');
                }
            string fName=get_fName(cam_ID, period * 60, vpath);
            string command=ffcommand(period, stream, fName);
            //logger
            string rec_process=...;
            set_rec_process(cam_ID, rec_process);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps
Garrett

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I'm looking for! Just one other thing: do you have idea if it's possibile to call other functions in my job_recording (eg. cam_enabled())? thanks

Comment: Hi, I don't see why not - you can add whatever you like to your RecordingJob class - so if you have the cam_enabled code elsewhere you can put that method into your recording class too

Comment: Yes ok I got it. Thank you again for the kind reply!